# Microsoft Graph API:Get all DriveItems from a Sites default drive: Invalid Url

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

trying to return all DriveItems that on a site.
I do the following to get the drive which returns a result

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/drive

but the following returns a "specified url is invalid"

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/drive/items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the root folders this way.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/drive/root/children
```